# how to use php sscanf with ampersand character

Tags: php, string, escaping, scanf, ampersand

I use php function **sscanf** to parse  string and extrac parameters.

This code :

```
$s='myparam1=hello&myparam2=world';
sscanf($s, 'myparam1=%s&myparam2=%s', $s1, $s2);
var_dump($s1, $s2);
```

displays :

```
string(20) "hello&myparam2=world" NULL
```

but i would like string **hello** in $s1 and strin **world** in $s2.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%s` isn't an equivalent to `\w` in regexp: it doesn't pick up only alphanumerics

```
$s='myparam1=hello&myparam2=world';
sscanf($s, 'myparam1=%[^&]&myparam2=%s', $s1, $s2);
var_dump($s1, $s2);
```

but using [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) might be a better option for you in this case

```
$s='myparam1=hello&myparam2=world';
parse_str($s, $sargs);
var_dump($sargs['myparam1'], $sargs['myparam2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Here is an example:

```
$string = 'myparam1=hello&myparam2=world';

// Will use exactly the same format
preg_match('/myparam1=(.*)&myparam2=(.*)/', $string, $matches); 
var_dump($matches); // Here ignore first result
echo("<br /><br />");

// Will match two values no matter of the param name
preg_match('/.*=(.*)&.*=(.*)/', $string, $matches); 
var_dump($matches); // Here ignore first result too
echo("<br /><br />");


// Will match all values no matter of the param name
preg_match('/=([^&]*)/', $string, $matches); 
var_dump($matches);
```

I all three cases the matches array will contain the params.

I'm pretty convinced that it's better.
Good luck!